# Errors within code to change the intersection of two Log Functions

Tags: plotting, evaluation

I have been asked to produce a "parametric log-log plot of s=f(y) as a function of t=g(y), where

```
f[y_] = y (2 y^2 - 5) (y^2 - 1)^{1/2} + 3 Log[y + (y^2 - 1)^{1/2}]
g[y_] = y (2 y^2 - 1) (y^2 - 1)^{1/2} - Log[y + (y^2 - 1)^{1/2}]
```

for y in [1,2]. I have also been asked to "display the points (t,s)=(g(y),f(y)) in Magenta".

If I have understood the question correctly, with lots of efforts, and assuming I did it correctly, I produced the following code which returned me the graph:

```
s[y_] = y (2 y^2 - 5) (y^2 - 1)^{1/2} + 3 Log[y + (y^2 - 1)^{1/2}]
t[y_] = y (2 y^2 - 1) (y^2 - 1)^{1/2} - Log[y + (y^2 - 1)^{1/2}]
LogLogPlot[{s[y], t[y]}, {y, 1, 2}, PlotLabels -> "Expressions", 
 PlotRange -> All, Mesh -> {{0}}, MeshStyle -> Magenta]
```

[image]

Now I think the ending question is asking me to change the color of the intersection to Magenta?

So adding

```
MeshFunctions -> {t[#] - s[#] &}
```

gives me some errors that "LogLogPlot::invmeshf: MeshFunctions->{t[#1]-s[#1]&} must be a pure function or a list of pure functions".

Can someone please tell me if I have understood the question correctly and if so, how do I change the color of the intersection to Magenta.

Many Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

f[y_] = y (2 y^2 - 5) (y^2 - 1)^(1/2) + 3 Log[y + (y^2 - 1)^(1/2)];

g[y_] = y (2 y^2 - 1) (y^2 - 1)^(1/2) - Log[y + (y^2 - 1)^(1/2)];

Reduce[f[y] == g[y], y, Reals]

(* y == 1 *)

f[1] == g[1] == 0

(* True *)

ParametricPlot[{g[y], f[y]}, {y, 1 + 10^-6, 2},
 PlotRange -> {{Automatic, Log[g[2]]}, {Automatic, Log[f[2]]}}, 
 ScalingFunctions -> {"Log", "Log"},
 Frame -> True,
 FrameLabel -> (Style[#, 12, Bold] & /@
    {"g(y)", "f(y)"}),
 ColorFunction -> (ColorData["Rainbow"][#3] &),
 PlotLegends -> BarLegend[{"Rainbow", {1, 2}},
   LegendLabel -> "y"]]
```

[image]